# scala, error while loading AnnotatedElement, class is broken

Tags: java, scala

I have just installed scala 2.9.2 with Java 1.8.0_45, ( on Ubuntu 14.04)
and on invoking the interactive scala shell with

```
$scala
```

I get the following error message:

> scala>[init] error while loading class AnnotatedElement, class file /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/rt.jar(java.lang.reflect/AnnotatedElement.class)' is broken, bad constant pool tag 18 at byte 76.

What is the problem here and how do I fix this?

Comment: BTW, any good reason for using an old version of Scala ?

Comment: That version of scala came with spark 1.4 as standard.

Comment: Thx - updated scala to 2.11.7